eslint will format <template> content within .vue file but not <script> content
I tried to add eslint support to my first vuejs3 project (after initially not checking eslint support during npm create vue@latest).
I basically tried to follow the docs:

Im using VSCode. With the project open I ran npm install -D eslint eslint-plugin-vue in the terminal.

Add the file eslint.config.js to the project root with the following content:
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue'
export default [
     ...pluginVue.configs['flat/recommended'],
    {
        rules: {
        }
    }
]


Install the official ESLintextension for VSCode.

Add the following settings to .vscode/settings.json:
    {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "eslint.format.enable": true,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll": "explicit"
        },
        "eslint.validate": [
            "javascript",
            "javascriptreact",
            "vue",
            "html"
        ]
    }



With those settings I notice the following behaviour:

Saving a .vue file will format the <template></templat> section of the file content but not the <script></script> section.

Interestingly saving the index.html file of the project will format it, but it seems to follow different formatting rules. Here is an example of the difference:
  <!-- index.html -->
  <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-main" data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -50%"
    data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" tabindex="0">
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>
  <!-- App.vue -->
  <div
    data-bs-spy="scroll"
    data-bs-target="#navbar-main"
    data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -50%"
    data-bs-smooth-scroll="true"
    tabindex="0"
  >
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>

In index.html it seems linebreaks are triggered by line length only, while within .vue files all attributes are put in separate lines.

Running npm run lint in the terminal gives the following result:

Invalid option '--ext' - perhaps you meant '-c'?
You're using eslint.config.js, some command line flags are no longer available. Please see https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface for details.


On the other hand running eslint --ext .js,.vue src or eslint "src/**/*.{js,vue}" will result in

eslint : The term 'eslint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. ....



I am wondering what is going wrong here and how I can fix my linting to be concise throughout the project and according to recommended rules.

I gave a few answers regarding those questions, not sure exactly what's wrong but you could maybe give it a check even if they are not the most recent ones, I think that they might still be relevant. Might be a missing ESlint package or maybe a conflict with some other linting/formatting in your VScode. Another very good rule of thumb regarding this kind of configuration is the fact that you need to restart the ESlint server in your VScode often to be sure that everything is properly reset in between configuration changes.

Not sure how good is this one but might maybe help: https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/

@kissu wow, that is quite a bit to read - thanks, I will go through the posts!

OK, at least one thing I got working so far: The command to run eslint from commandline is defined in the package.json - I copied the configuration from an empty new vue project with eslint support checked. This however is an older version and uses a eslintrc file, while I use eslint.config.js where the --ext flag is not supported. So at least now I can run it manually.

@kissu Could you confirm (or not) the following: I have read some more through the user guide you have linked. It says that to support <script setup> one needs the vue-eslint-parser package. However, according to this issues on github, it seems v9 is not yet supported for it. I think this might explain my problem - the solution would be to downgrade the linter to a version <9.

That might be it yes. You can always use a non-flat config or downgrade I suppose yes!
